# Incorrect startup project in Visual Studio 2013 Community edition after changing TFS folder location

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a Solution in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition running on 64 bit Windows 10 Pro, which contains 8 projects, two of which are Windows services, and the rest of which are either Windows Forms apps or web sites. I have been working with this Solution successfully for the last several months. Typically the startup project is set to one or the other of the WinForms projects, and it all worked exactly as you would expect.

Our company uses Team Foundation Server. Today I had to move my TFS folder to a different location.  That all worked well (eventually) except that now, when I set the startup project to one of the WinForms projects and Start Debugging (exactly the same as I always did), it tries, unsuccessfully, to start each of the Windows services in turn, before finally starting the correct "startup" project.  The project which is set as the startup project does display correctly in bold in Solution Explorer.  Also, one of the errant Services comes before the desired startup project in Solution Explorer, and one comes after.

I have searched for hints online, and found and tried many things:

- Reboot
- Verify that the Solution properties specify the correct "Single
  startup project"
- Change the Solution startup properties to "Current selection"
- Delete the suo file
- Delete all the files from my local hard drive and retrieve them fresh
  from TFS
- I am not using Resharper or any other add-in, other than TFS

If I change the Startup project to one of the other WinForms apps, then that is the project that starts after the two services fail to start.  If the setting is for "Current selection", then that project starts after the two services fail to start.

I am stumped.  Any suggestions I have not already tried?

Thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  For the two Windows Services projects, there is a project property called "Always Start When Debugging".  Setting this to False solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the project files of the WinForm apps. They could hold the launch paths to the services hardcoded to the old location. Look for the two properties PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvent or the two targets BeforeBuild and AfterBuild. The two properties can be edited from the Project Property dialog, but in order to edit the two targets you need to open the project file in a text editor.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>....</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>....</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  ...
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  ...
  </Target>
```

Paths should be made relative so that they are not depending on every developer getting them to a specific directory.